# Playframework 2.2: Validation are fire, without add validations annotations on pojo

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, validationerror

When i submit the form, the playframework fire the validations, but in the pojo class i am not define any `Annotations` for validation. The validations are fire only on two fields. My code as below:

POJO Class:

```
public class User {
public int id;
public String name;
public int age;

public User() {}

public User(int id, String name, int age){
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "User [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", age=" + age + "]";
}
}
```

My Controller Method:

```
public Result saveUser() {
    Form<User> userData = userForm.bindFromRequest();
    if(userData.hasErrors()){
        flash("error", "Please enter valid values");
        return badRequest(add_user.render(userData));
    }
    User user = userData.get();
    boolean result = userService.addNewUser(user);
    if(result){
        flash("success", String.format("Add user success %s", user));
    }else{
        flash("error", String.format("Fail to save user, Please contact admin %s", user));
    }
    return redirect(routes.UserController.newUsers());
}
```

HTML Form:

```
@(userForm: Form[com.harmeetsingh13.entities.User])
@import helper._
@import helper.twitterBootstrap._

@main("New User"){
<h1 style="margin-left: 20px;">User Form</h1>
@helper.form(action = com.harmeetsingh13.controllers.routes.UserController.saveUser(), 
        'id -> "userForm", 'style -> "margin-left: 20px;"){
    <fieldset>
        <legend>User (@userForm("name").valueOr("New"))</legend>
        @helper.inputText(userForm("id"), '_label -> "ID")
        @helper.inputText(userForm("name"), '_label -> "Name")
        @helper.inputText(userForm("age"), '_label -> "Age")
    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save" />
}
}
```

When i submit the form, i get following error:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I don't know , why this happen, but `play-framework` do by default with primitive types. when i change data type of my pojo `User` from `int` to `String`, then the validations are not fire automatically. Still i am not found anything about these type of validation in `play-framework` but this really stuck the developer.